# When analytic continuation from discrete set is unique?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Under which additional conditions an analytic continuation of a function defined on an infinite discrete set of points (i.e. no limit points) can be made unique? Any theorem on the subject please?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One theorem in this vein I know of is **Carlson's theorem**, which basically says that if we start with a function $f$ that maps from the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$, to the complex plane, and which grows *at most exponentially*, at i.e.

$$|f(n)| \in O(a^n)$$

for some base $a > 1$, then it admits *no more than one* analytic extension $F$ to domain $\mathbb{C}$ such that, along the *imaginary* axis, the growth bound

$$|F(iy)| \in O(e^{\pi|y|})$$

holds.

Although, it's more often stated as that if both bounds above hold for a given complex function $F$ that is zero at each integer, then $F$ is identically zero (i.e. $F = (z \mapsto 0)$).

One reference of use is, which also gives a slightly more general form for subsets of natural numbers:

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1956-083-02/S0002-9947-1956-0081944-8/S0002-9947-1956-0081944-8.pdf

Comment: @Ignat Fialkovskiy : Actually, I'm not sure. I checked some other sources and it looks like that may have been a mistake, so I qualify it to the NNs only now.

Comment: Actually, in this form the statement is even stronger (as I now understand). If a function vanishes on $\mathbb{Z}$ it does so on $\mathbb{N}$ as well.

Answer (score 2):

"Under which additional conditions..." is a little broad for a definitive answer. *One* situation where this happens is when we place appropriate growth conditions on the functions. For example:

> > Let $D=D(0,1)$. Suppose $(z_n)\subset D$, $|x_n|\to 1$ but $\sum(1-|z_n|)=\infty$. Suppose $f,g\in H(D)$ are *bounded*. If $f(z_n)=g(z_n)$ for all $n$  then $f=g$.

Proof:  Look for "Blaschke condition" on wikipedia or in Rudin _Real and Complex Analysis. (If you don't find a suitable article on wikipedia say so and one will appear...)

Another example: Say  $f\in PW$ (for "Paley-Wiener") if $f$ is entire, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(t)|^2\,dt<\infty$ and $f(z)\le ce^{\pi|z|}$.

> > If $f,g\in PW$ and $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$ then $f=g$.

Comment: Thanks! Although your first example seems not to be applicable in my case (my set $D$ is unbounded), the second one is exactly the type of condition I was thinking about - appropriate growth and square integrability. It looks pretty similar to the Carlson's theorem from @The_Sympathizer's comment, is it connected?

Comment: Do you have any reference please for the PW example?

Comment: Say $h=f-g$. The Paley-Wiener theorem (see for example Rudin _RCA_) says there exists $F\in  L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ such that $h=\hat F$, the Fourier transform of $h$. The hypothesis now says $\int_{-\pi}^\pi F(t)e^{int}\,dt=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z$; hence $F=0$.

Comment: typo: ... the Fourier transform of $F$.